# Adding an object to SimpleListProperty

Tags: list

I'm tyring to add an object to a SimpleListProperty, However when i run the program the IDE throws a java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException. What is going wrong?

This is my code

```
 private final SimpleListProperty<ObjectModel> list;

public constructor(ObjectModel object) {
    this.list = new SimpleListProperty<>();
    addObject(object);
}

public void addObject(ObjectModel object) {
        this.list.add(object);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass an ObservableList in the constructor. SimpleListProperty is just a property.

I would do something like this:

```
public constructor() {
ObservableList<ObjectModel> observableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(new ArrayList<ObjectModel>());
list = new SimpleListProperty<ObjectModel>(observableList);
}

public void addObject(ObjectModel object) {
    list.add(object);
}
```

I would call constructor() and AddObject separately. AddObject is anyways public.

More info here: http://notepad2.blogspot.com/2015/11/javafx-how-to-use-listproperty.html?m=1

Comment: Could you eleberate what i need to do with the constructor?
Currently i do not get the exception anymore but it the list stays null, while i add.